# Drawing dynamic circles based on input value

Tags: circles

Is there a formula that will allow me to calculate the radius of a circle based on an input value?  The input value could be as small as zero or as large as $10^7$, or larger.  The circle is restricted to a minimum radius of $10$ and a maximum radius of $100$.

Does anyone know how to calculate something like this?

**UPDATE**

The input values correspond to state/country population.  I want to calculate the radius (how big the circle should be) of the circle based on the input value.

Comment: What does the input correspond to?

Comment: What is the input value supposed to be?  If it is the radius of the circle, it is easy.  Just raise everything below $10$ to $10$, and lower everything above $100$ to $100$.  Explaining why this is not acceptable may help you define the problem better.

Comment: I made an edit, hope it helps.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The update would have been useful in the original post.

Comment: Is this supposed to mean that on an input of say $200, 300$ and $400$, we ascribe the radius $10$ to $200$, $55$ to $300$ and $100$ to $400$?

Comment: Yes.  The smallest input value would have the smallest radius, and the largest input value would have the largest radius.  Each value in between would have a different radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll expand on what I understood from your comment.

Let $\{x_i\}$ be the set of inputs.

Then the range of inputs is given by $\max\{x_i\}-\min\{x_i\}$.

The radius for the $i$th input is then given by

$$R=10+90\left(\frac{x_i-\min\{x_i\}}{\max\{x_i\}-\min\{x_i\}}\right)$$

Comment: This works!  Though, I may need to adjust my minimum radius value, it is too small for what I want.

Answer (score 2):

For this application, I would just make the area of the circle proportional to the population.  Let $R=\sqrt{\text{maximum population of a state/city}}$  Then plot each circle as $r=100\sqrt{\frac {\text{population}}R}$, boosting the ones you want to show that are below $r=10$ to $r=10$ to satisfy your minimum.  But I don't understand the minimum.

Comment: This is an important point - whatever the scaling factor, for visualization it's important to have area (and not radius) proportional to population.

Answer (score 0):

$$r=10+\frac { 90 }{ { 10 }^{ 7 } } P$$ where P is your input and r is the radius of the circle.

Comment: Just to be sure, does 10 represent the minimum radius?  What does 90 represent?  I assume 10^7 represents the maximum value in the ranse of possible values?

Comment: $10$ is minimum radius,$90 = (100-10)$ = (maximum radius-minimum radius), $10^7-0 = 10^7$ population interval. In this case minimum population is zero so you can jsut write $10^7$$